# Not able to parse through xmlReaderForMemory api

Tags: libxml2

My code generate the following string,

```
XmlWriter obj1;
obj1.StartDocWriting("MyObject.xml");
obj1.SetRootNode("Object");
obj1.CreateChildNodeToRootWithProperty("age","20");         
obj1.CreateChildNodeToRootWithProperty("name","xyz");
obj1.xml_to_string(outbuf);
```

o/p xml string,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Object><age>20</age><name>xyz</name></Object>
```

when I am trying to parse it,i am getting the following error,

> Entity: line 3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the
>   document

```
Here is my parsing code,

std:string inbuf = "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Object><age>20</age><name>xyz</name></Object>"

 XmlTextReader obj1;
 xmlTextReaderPtr readPtr =  obj1.parseBuffer(inbuf.c_str(),10000);

xmlTextReaderPtr XmlTextReader::parseBuffer( const char *aInBuffer,
                                             int aInSize,
                                             const char * aInUrl,
                                             const char * aInEncoding,
                                             int aInOptions )
{
    xmlReader = xmlReaderForMemory( aInBuffer, aInSize, aInUrl, aInEncoding, aInOptions );
    if( xmlReader == NULL )
    {
       printf("reader is null");
       // LOG(LOG_INFO, "parseBuffer:: xmlReaderForMemory return NULL\n");
    }
    return xmlReader;
}
```

Comment: You should provide the code that does the parsing. Also, the "xml string" you provided contains only 2 lines. The error says "in line 3". So probably there is some garbage at the end of the (actual) file. What type is `outbuf` and how do you write it to a file?

Comment: Here is my parsing code,

Comment: outbuf is std::string type

Comment: '10000' is wrong - your string is much less than ten thousands of bytes

Comment: Not sure how `xmlReaderFromMemory` works internally, but try `obj1.parseBuffer(inbuf.c_str(), inbuf.length())` instead (also see @keltar's comment).